# bootstrap select box - center text

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, text-align

I have the following bootstrap 4.3.1 dropdown select box.  Unable to center the text ('nothing selected') in the select box.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://www.sailwbob.com/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://www.sailwbob.com/bootstrap/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<select id='test' multiple data-style="bg-white border border-dark pill px-4 py-3   " data-selected-text-format="count" class="selectpicker justify-content-center  w-50">
            <option>United Kingdom</option>
            <option>United States</option>
            <option>France</option>
            <option>Germany</option>
            <option>Italy</option>
        </select>




<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.sailwbob.com/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.sailwbob.com/bootstrap/bootstrap-select.min.js" </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.bootstrap-select .dropdown-toggle .filter-option-inner-inner {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
```

add text-center class to div instead:

```
<div class="filter-option-inner-inner text-center">Nothing selected</div>
```

or the parent:

```
<div class="filter-option-inner text-center"></div>
```

or the "grand-parent" (lol):

```
<div class="filter-option text-center"></div>
```

Comment: I'd add `text-overflow: ellipsis` just in case

Comment: that's more of a brute force approach.  Looking for an elegant bootstrap class to add